# In jQuery, how do you combine asynchronous calls, including json and jsonp

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, jquery-deferred, promise

I'm trying to call three services using jQuery. The first two get the data and the third makes an update using the data.

Part One: I want to get my bank account information:

- From Foo Bank, I want to get my checking
- From Bar Bank, I want to get my savings

Part Two: When I've successfully gotten the information from both banks, I want to upload that to my personal checkbook on my own service.

Here is some pseudo code that looks like Javascript. It's sort of what I would write if I could write synchronous code to do the job, which I know that I can't.

```
--PSEUDO CODE

var go = function () {
    var acctId;

    acctId = 12345;
    var myInfo = getAccounts(acctId);
    updateCheckbook(myInfo);
}

var getAccounts = function(acctId){
    var myInfo;

    myInfo = {
        id: acctId,
        fooDollars: GetFooBank(acctId),
        barDollars: GetBarBank(acctId)
    };

    return myInfo;
}

var updateCheckbook(myInfo){
    $.post('http://mySite.com/checkbook/', myInfo);
}

//I want to get the amount from my foo bank account
//Foo Bank uses a web service that allows cross site access
//No bank would ever do this, but I just want to understand how to with $.getJSON.
var fooDollars = function (id) {
    var value;
    $.getJSON('http://foobank.com/accounts/' + id, null, function (data) {
        value = data.checking;
    });

    //I'm pretty sure this is wrong with an asynchronous call.
    return value;
};

var barDollars = function (id) {
    //have to use jsonp for bar bank
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://barbank.com/accounts/' + id + '&callback=updateBar',
        dataType: 'jsonp'
    });

    //Not really sure how to return a value from a jsonp ajax call
    return value;
};

function updateBar(data) {
    //Need to take data.savings and get the value back to getAccounts.
    //How? I have no idea. 
}
```

I kind of get what jQuery's deferred methods do, but I'm a bit mixed up in how all the pieces fit together. In particular:

1. In part one, I need to wait for both bank account services are done before moving to the next step. jQuery when deals with waiting for multiple deferrals, but I was unable to understand how you wait for multiple functions returning values.
2. In Part 1, Foo Bank, I'm calling a `$.getJSON`. I want to take the data object returned and grab data.checking. How do I get that information back into getAccounts() ?
3. In Part 1, Bar Bank, Simlar to 2, except how do I do that with JSONP ?
4. If I'm completely off track and should be looking at it differently, that feedback is appreciated as well.

Comment: asynchronous functions don't return values. That's the biggest flaw in your code. `fooDollars` can't return `value`. `getAccounts` can't return `myInfo`.

Comment: What approach would you use to change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The knack is return promises, not values, from `fooDollars()` and `barDollars()` (and for good measure from `updateCheckbook()`). `$.when().then()` in `go()` waits for both promises to be fulfilled before firing its callback.

Sticking with you current line up of functions, and translating (as far as possible) pseudo- into real-code, I get the following :

```
var go = function () {
    var acctId = 12345;
    $.when.apply(null, getAccounts(acctId)).then(function(a1, a2){
        return updateCheckbook({
            id: acctId,
            fooDollars: a1[0].checking,
            barDollars: a2[0].savings
        });
    }).done(function() {
        alert("Checkbook updated");
    });
}

var getAccounts = function(acctId){
    return [
        fooDollars(acctId),
        barDollars(acctId)
    ];
}

var updateCheckbook(myInfo){
    return $.post('http://mySite.com/checkbook/', myInfo);
}

var fooDollars = function (id) {
    return $.getJSON('http://foobank.com/accounts/' + id);
};

var barDollars = function (id) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'http://barbank.com/accounts/' + id,
        dataType: 'jsonp'
    });
};
```

This will simplify slightly, if you wanted, by cutting out `getAccounts()` and calling `fooDollars()` and `barDollars()` directly from `go()`.

Only bit I'm not too sure about is the jsonp. Might need some work.

Comment: Personally, I'd return a promise from `go`, too

Comment: Good point @Alnitak, you certainly could, just in case it's needed for further thenning/dunning where `go()` is called.

Comment: Looks good. My only question would be surrounding the $when vs when.apply. You switched the return type for getAccounts from a myInfo object to an array. What if you had left it as a myInfo object?

Comment: I nearly included a note on this point. Remember we're concerned with promises now, not values. The original object returned by `getAccounts()` was a set of values but is now two promises wrapped in an array, which is directly usable by `$.when.apply()`. The original values object is now composed in `go()` only when both accounts have successfully responded. I could have factored the code differently with `$.when.apply()` or `$.when()` inside `getAccounts()` and returned a promise of the final object. That would be a more faithful analogue of your original code.

Comment: Actually, looking at it again, I would probably just remove `getAccounts()` altogether and replace `.when.apply` with `.when(fooDollars(acctId),barDollars(acctId))`

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was hinting at in the last-but-one paragraph in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Asynchronous functions don't return values. That's the biggest flaw in your code. `fooDollars` can't return `value`. `getAccounts` can't return `myInfo` (assuming `getAccounts` performs ajax too).

Instead, have your functions return the `jqXHR` object (which is also a promise object).

```
var fooDollars = function (id) {

    return $.getJSON('http://foobank.com/accounts/' + id);

};
```

do the same with `getAccounts` (i assume it does ajax too), then you can do this:

```
$.when(fooDollars('foo'),getAccounts('bar')).done(function(fD,gA){
    console.log(fD[0].checking);
    console.log(gA[0]);
})
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand where fD and gA are coming from. Is fD just coming from data from fooDollars? 

What happened to the call to the Bar Bank? 

getAccounts is just the wrapper around both fooDollars and barDollars to say that both must finish before doing updateCheckbook.

Comment: Ah, sorry i misunderstood then. replace getAccounts with the call to barbank then. fD is an array that contains the arguments that would have normally been passed to the fooDollars success callback. I named it fD for fooDollars so it would hopefully be easy to remember that it represents the data returned from fooDollars

Comment: OK, That makes sense. The first argument that comes back from success is the data object. Does the same code work with jsonp?